# How to validate Html, Css and Javascript content in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In my form I have a text area.The textarea has to allow only html,css and javascript content. I have to validate the text area content is html or css or javascript. How to check the Text area contain data is html content or  css or javascript.

Answer (score 2):

```
   code = // fetch the text area value here
   if (code.match(/<(br|basefont|hr|input|source|frame|param|area|meta|!--|col|link|option|base|img|wbr|!DOCTYPE).*?>|<(a|abbr|acronym|address|applet|article|aside|audio|b|bdi|bdo|big|blockquote|body|button|canvas|caption|center|cite|code|colgroup|command|datalist|dd|del|details|dfn|dialog|dir|div|dl|dt|em|embed|fieldset|figcaption|figure|font|footer|form|frameset|head|header|hgroup|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|html|i|iframe|ins|kbd|keygen|label|legend|li|map|mark|menu|meter|nav|noframes|noscript|object|ol|optgroup|output|p|pre|progress|q|rp|rt|ruby|s|samp|script|section|select|small|span|strike|strong|style|sub|summary|sup|table|tbody|td|textarea|tfoot|th|thead|time|title|tr|track|tt|u|ul|var|video).*?<\/\2/)) {
      $(this).after("<span>This is HTML</span>");
   }
   else if (code.match(/(([ trn]*)([a-zA-Z-]*)([.#]{1,1})([a-zA-Z-]*)([ trn]*)+)([{]{1,1})((([ trn]*)([a-zA-Z-]*)([:]{1,1})((([ trn]*)([a-zA-Z-0-9#]*))+)[;]{1})*)([ trn]*)([}]{1,1})([ trn]*)/)) {
      $(this).after("<span>This is CSS</span>");
   }
   else {
      $(this).after("<span>This is JS</span>");
   }
```